# The wrong date is coming up in my mysli database?

Tags: php, date, mysqli

I am struggling to get the correct date entered into my database when someone signs up on my site.  I am able to get a date entered into my database using the following code:

```
 $insertdate = date('m-d-Y', strtotime($_POST['Date']));

 $sql = $con->query("INSERT INTO BD (sfm_form_submision_date, FirstName, LastName, Email, UserName, Password) Values( '{$insertdate}', '{$FName}', '{$LName}', '{$Email}', '{$UName}','{$PW}')"); 
 header('Location: login.php');
```

My problem is that the date in my database reads:

```
12-31-1969
```

This is driving me crazy as the date on my computer is `6/5/2016`.

Any suggestions?
Thanks!

My code for processing is:

```
$sql = $con->query("INSERT INTO BD (_sfm_form_submision_date_, FirstName, LastName, Email, UserName, Password) Values( '{$insertdate}',  '{$FName}', '{$LName}', '{$Email}', '{$UName}','{$PW}')");
header('Location: login.php');
```

I fear I am overthinking this. All I need is a simple way to enter the current date when the submit button in pressed.

Comment: In database your date field type is "DATE" or varchar ?

Comment: It was varchar and I changed it to date now I get 0000-00-00

Comment: Can you post the code you are inserting with? What does `strtotime($_POST['Date'])` output as?

Comment: what's the value of `$_POST['Date']`?

Comment: That means `strtotime($_POST['Date'])` encountered a date it couldn't parse, and returned 0. 0 is January 1, 1970 (your date, with some timezone mayhem).

Comment: this format wrong. please change your field dattype to "DATE" format and look at my answer. can you give us the value of $_POST['Date']

Comment: @ScottSchoener please give us the value of  $_POST['Date'], where is coming and which format you use when post ?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the current date by removing `{$insertdate}` an replacing it with `CURDATE()` in my code as specified below:

```
$sql = $con->query("INSERT INTO BD (_sfm_form_submision_date_, FirstName, LastName, Email, UserName, Password) Values( '{$insertdate}',  '{$FName}', '{$LName}', '{$Email}', '{$UName}','{$PW}')");
header('Location: login.php');
```